# Javascript regular expression to match various strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a question that I can't resolve. I have strings that contains hashtags, for example '#question' or '#idea'.

The question is how extract the hashtag?

```
var hashtag = str.match(/#question?#idea?/i);
```

Is this regexp correct?

Answer (score 3):

Your line

```
var hashtag = str.match(/#question?#idea?/i);
```

checks whether a string contains a literal `#questio`, optionally followed by `n`, followed by `#ide`, optionally followed by `a`. If that's the case, `hashtag[0]` will contain the matched text. This is obviously not what you want.

Try this:

```
// match a #, followed by either "question" or "idea"
var myregexp = /#(question|idea)\b/i;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1]; // will contain "question" or "idea"
} else {
    result = "";
}
```

The `\b` at the end of the regex is a word boundary anchor. It ensures that only `#question` but not `#questionnaire` will be matched.

If you don't know the names of the hashtags beforehand, use

```
var myregexp = /#(\w+)/;
```

(this allows ASCII letters, digits and underscore as possible hashtag characters - I don't know if those are the only valid characters. If not, you can use a character class. For example, to allow dashes, too:

```
var myregexp = /#([\w-]+)/;
```

Answer (score 1):

No your regex is not correct.

```
/#question?#idea?/i
```

You search for each character in your regex, in this order. The `?` makes the character before comes 0 or 1 times, the i at the end makes the expression ignoreCase, i.e. treat upper and lower case the same. You will find:

```
#question#idea
#questio#ide
#questio#idea
#QUEStion#IDea
```

but not

```
#question
#idea
```

Do you have a fixed set of tags, can they contain only letters, or also numbers, or other characters?

You can check your regexes e.g. here online [My example](http://regexr.com?2tbj2)

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "/foo=bar?#quesAion#dwdad";
var regi = new RegExp("(#[a-z0-9_-]*)", "gi");
var hashtag = str.match(regi);
```

Hashtag will be an array of found strings or null if not found any.